# Building a Newsstand App

Tags: ios, newsstand-kit

I am looking at learning to do a newsstand app, and needed some basic information.  I know about setting up consumables, non-consumables, and subscriptions, but it is the communication with the content server side that I get hung up on.  In building the app, what all info do I need from the magazine publisher?  Server address, passwords...I really don't know what all I need to effectively have the app communicate with them, Apple, and deliver the content.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is good tutorial how to create Newsstand application  - [link](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also go the easy road and release your magazine through something like - http://uninkd.com.